# Netbeans main function using external assembly function

Tags: c, netbeans, assembly

I have a program (`main.c`) that calls an external assembly function (`function.s`).

The `main.c` declare and use the assembly function:

```
extern int function(int n);
res = function(3);
```

It works:

```
> gcc function.s main.c -o test
```

But, how can I have to configure Netbeans to build and debug it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps an issue for copying the code.

Writing from scratch works well.

That's all